# How to show an optional header in markdown for apiary?

Tags: apiary.io

How to indicate that one particular header of a request is optional with the markdown of apiary?

My code:

- Request
  The apiKey can be passed in the header (note the camelcase for "apiKey")
  The Content-Encoding: gzip is optional, only if you gzip the entity

  - Headers

    ```
    apiKey: `42452-eofefo-4534535` (optional)
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Encoding: gzip (optional)
    ```

Is the above ok?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of January 2016, **it's not possible**.

On the other hand—if you go to the [API Blueprint Roadmap](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/wiki/Roadmap), there's [MSON Parameters and Headers](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint-rfcs/pull/3) feature which is currently in the RFC stage; this will enable you to describe HTTP Headers in the [MSON](https://github.com/apiaryio/mson) syntax and mark each HTTP Header as required/optional (see below).

```
+ Response 200 (application/json)
    + Headers
        + Date (Date, optional) - Date at which the message was originated
```

Hoping MSON Headers will land soon.